# Symfony JsonResponse not maintining array order

Tags: php, symfony, jsonresponse

I've a first function which returns an array with a specific order (see the picture below).

```
    private function getScenarioPartners(Request $request){
    $users = array();
    /.../
    uasort($users,array($this,"userComparison"));
    return $users;
}
```

[image]

The seconde one aggregate multiple data from different methods and return a`JsonResponse`.

```
        return new JsonResponse(array(
        'users'              => $this->getScenarioPartners($request),
        /.../
    ),201);
```

The JsonResponse object is not respecting the order returned by the `getScenarioPartners` method which return the users array.

How Can I keep the initial order returned by my first method ?

[image]

Comment: Is index important in this case? If not, you could reindex the array once you have it sorted the way you want to.

Comment: Do you care about the index of the array, the order of the array, or both?

Comment: JSON objects with numeric indexes are reordered in javascript, you could usa a string key to avoid this.